# How to change the font and size of image in QTextDocument?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextdocument

I want to print some text and image designed by qtdesigner.

How could I change font and another format in `QTextDocument`?

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
        cursor.insertImage('logo4.jpg')
        cursor.insertBlock()
        cursor.insertText('MY TEXT')
        
        document.print_(printer)


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_print_previw = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 270, 251, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setObjectName("pushButton_print_previw")
        self.pushButton_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 270, 251, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_print.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_print.setObjectName("pushButton_print")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        ############################################################
        self.pushButton_print_previw.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
        ############################################################

        ############################################################
        self.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        ############################################################



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print Preview"))
        self.pushButton_print.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.print_(printer)` is very convenient but it is not a little flexible.

Because you don't use `QTextEdit`, you must edit the format information by your code only. (except for setHtml in advance.)
If you draw `QPrinter` document as you like, you can use `QPainter`.

Normarly, although `QPainter` is used in `paintEvent(self, event)`, only if you set a subclass of `QPaintDevice` to constructor of `QPainter`, you can draw as you like.
But you must calculate the allocation exactly.

QPrinter is a subclass of `QPaintDevice`.

**Trap**

---

The topleft of `QPainter.drawText` is the bottom line of Text.

<sub>(x, y)→</sub> MY TEXT

---

Here is the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def handlePrint(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

    def handlePreview(self):
        dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
#        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
#        cursor.insertImage('logo4.jpg')
#        cursor.insertBlock()
#        cursor.insertText('MY TEXT')
#        document.print_(printer)
        documentRootFrameFormat = document.rootFrame().frameFormat()
        documentLeftMargin = documentRootFrameFormat.leftMargin()
        documentTopMargin = documentRootFrameFormat.topMargin()
        drawn_im = QtGui.QImage("logo4.jpg")
        drawn_im_height = drawn_im.height()        

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(printer)
        painter.drawImage(documentLeftMargin, documentTopMargin, drawn_im)
        painter_font = painter.font()
        #you can set flag which font is used.
        custom_font = QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI Light", 18)        
        fontMetricsF = QtGui.QFontMetricsF(custom_font)
        painter.save()
        painter.setFont(custom_font)
        height_fontMetricsF = fontMetricsF.height()
        painter.drawText(documentLeftMargin, documentTopMargin + drawn_im_height + height_fontMetricsF, 'MY TEXT')
        painter.restore()



    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_print_previw = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 270, 251, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setObjectName("pushButton_print_previw")
        self.pushButton_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 270, 251, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.pushButton_print.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_print.setObjectName("pushButton_print")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        ############################################################
        self.pushButton_print_previw.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
        ############################################################

        ############################################################
        self.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
        ############################################################



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_print_previw.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print Preview"))
        self.pushButton_print.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Print"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**My Result**
[image: My Result]

If you want to use `QTextCursor`, you can set Font & format by using the method of `QTextCursor`.

You can get the similar result by this code.
I recommend this if you don't hope high control.

**Other Solution**

```
def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
    document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
    
    cursor.insertImage("logo4.jpg")
    cursor.insertBlock()
    charFormat = cursor.charFormat()
    charFormat.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Segoe UI Light", 18))
    cursor.insertText('MY TEXT', charFormat)

    document.print_(printer)
```